# How to make ScrollView scrollable when windowSoftInputMode is adjustPan?

Tags: android, scrollview, bottomnavigationview

I use `BottomNavigationView` in my activity. When keyboard opens and `windowSoftInputMode` is **NOT** `adjustPan`, `BottomNavigationView` is shown over keyboard. That's why I set `windowSoftInputMode` as `adjustPan`. But, now, my `ScrollView` is not scrollable. When I change `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustResize`, `ScrollView` is working fine. The following structure is scrollable, when `windowSoftInputMode` is set to `adjustResize`, but not scrollable, if `adjustPan` is set:

```
   <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
     <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

     <!-- Other stuff --> 

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

`ScrollView` is used as root view. So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try adding `android:isScrollContainer="false"` in your scrollview tag and use `adjustPan`

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help.